# Login through multi browser parallely- Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing, cross-browser, facebook-login

I am trying to login to facebook.com in parallel on 2 different browsers (***Chrome*** and ***firefox***).
Although both the browser opens the URL, in one browser no credentials are being entered, but in the second browser, the credentials are getting appended twice.
Due to this, my tests are failing.

I have used parallel as tests and methods as well. But it is not working.
MyWebDriver's driver instances are static, so there should not be any confusion when dealing with different browser types as both the browsers are opening this url.

Below is my testng.xml

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Suite" verbose="1" thread-count="3" parallel="tests">
<listeners>
<listener class-name = "myTestingProject.Tests.TestListener"/>
<listener class-name = "myTestingProject.Tests.RetryListener"/>
<listener class-name = "myTestingProject.Tests.ReportListener"/>
</listeners>
 <test name="TestCorrectCredChrome">
  <parameter name= "correctUsername" value ="user123@gmail.com"/>
  <parameter name= "CorrectPassword" value ="password"/>
  <parameter name= "browser" value ="Chrome"/>
    <parameter name= "url" value ="https://www.facebook.com/"/>
    <parameter name= "waitTime" value ="50"/>
    <classes>
    <class name="myTestingProject.Tests.BaseWebDriverTest"/>
      <class name="myTestingProject.Tests.LoginTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="TestCorrectCredFirefox">
  <parameter name= "correctUsername" value ="user123@gmail.com"/>
  <parameter name= "CorrectPassword" value ="password"/>
  <parameter name= "browser" value ="Firefox"/>
    <parameter name= "url" value ="https://www.facebook.com/"/>
    <parameter name= "waitTime" value ="50"/>
    <classes>
    <class name="myTestingProject.Tests.BaseWebDriverTest"/>
      <class name="myTestingProject.Tests.LoginTest"/>
    </classes>

  </test> <!-- Test -->

</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Below is the code for my custom MyWebDriver class which has methods of selenium webdriver

```java
public class MyWebDriver {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static int waitTime = 60;

    public static void openUrl(String url)
    {
        driver.get(url);
    }
    public static void closeDriver()
    {
        driver.close();
    }
    public static void quitDriver()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
//other methods like findElements etc
```

Below is the code for the testclass Basedriver which intializes the MyWebdriver

```java
public class BaseWebDriverTest extends MyWebDriver{

    @BeforeClass
    @Parameters({"url","browser","waitTime"})
    public void init(String url, String browser,String waitTime) {
    System.out.println("Current Thread ID - "+Thread.currentThread().getId());

         if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
             System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\eclipse-workspace\\project\\resources\\chromedriver.exe");
             MyWebDriver.driver = new ChromeDriver();
         } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
             System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\eclipse-workspace\\project\\resources\\geckodriver.exe");
             MyWebDriver.driver = new FirefoxDriver();
         }
        MyWebDriver.waitTime = Integer.parseInt(waitTime);
        MyWebDriver.openUrl(url);
    }
}
```

Below is the Testclass for Login, which feeds credentials.

```java
public class LoginTest extends BaseWebDriverTest{

  @Test
  @Parameters({"correctUsername","CorrectPassword"})
  public void loginCorrectCredenential(String correctUname,
          String correctPwd) throws InterruptedException {
     MyWebDriverWait.waitUntilVisibilityOfElementLocatedBy("id", Login.getPasswordId());
     MyWebDriverWait.waitUntilVisibilityOfElementLocatedBy("id", Login.getUserId());
     MyWebDriver.driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(correctUname);
     MyWebDriver.driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys(correctPwd);
  }
```

Since my webdriver is static here, it is opening two browsers, 1st chrome and then firefox. But the credentials are written only on firefox and the credentials are repeated. Please see attached image. Left one is chrome and the right one is firefox.

Please suggest as to how this can be resolved. I have tried doing this using grid too but the problem still remains.

[ChromeFirefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsWmR.png)

Comment: Please include relevant code and configurations in your question, not as pictures. Pictures mean that people who might help you will have to type out your code, can't search it and on some devices it won't display well enough. to read. For people with accessibility issues, the screen readers won't read it, while your choice of colours may make it impossible to read.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Yes, @Dragonthoughts is right. You can edit your question and add your code. When your code has 4 spaces from the left, it will be formatted in color as code. Hope to hear from you soon.